# drupal site UI stopped working for reasons unknown

Tags: drupal-7

Am working on a drupal-7 site but it suddenly has stopped showing the correct theme and just shows a garbled UI.

have thought about it and cannot seem to locate the reason for this.

wanted to ask that if any suggestions can be given of this . secondly is there a way to refresh the drupal site (i.e. run the drupal site installation process again without re-installing/deleting any physical file/database).

hope to have made the question clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue solved. problem came apparently from a module (custom made) which had function name same as used somewhere else on site.

thank you for time and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Two common reasons.

1. The last thing you did broke it.
2. Someone hacked it.

Reinstall the exact same version of drupal in a new folder with a new empty database. If the only things you changed were the content (no PHP patches etc), then you should be able to simply switch databases. You could also diff the installations to see if any files were altered.

Comment: thank you for the comment.. one thing that was noticed is that other themes seems to be working. but personally cannot